# WPF button call StackPanel visibilityconverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My task is to change visibility of StackPanel when user click button, due to value of that button this StackPanel can have special function. For this reason I implement VisibilityConverter which supposed to change visibility when StackPanelVis is true to Visible. Code for converter:

```
  public class StakPanelToVisible : IValueConverter
  {
     public static bool StackPanelVis;
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      { 
          value = StackPanelVis;
          return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
      }
     public object ConvertBack(...) {empty}
```

When user press the button in cause command that pass value to StackPanelToVisible code for command in VM:

```
    public RelayCommand SetAddingButton
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(SetAddingProperties, true);
        }
    }

    public bool StackPanelVis { get; private set; }

    private void SetAddingProperties()
    {
        TextInducator = "Add";
        StakPanelToVisible.StackPanelVis = true;

    }
```

Code for view in XAML:

```
   <StackPanel  Margin="5 10 5 0" Grid.Column="1"  >
      <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding StackPanelVis, Converter=
        {StaticResource StakPanelToVisible}}" >
       some elements in StackPanel 
   <Button Content="Add" Margin="5 5 5 1" 
                Padding="2"  x:Name="AddPosition_button" 
                 Command="{Binding  SetAddingButton }"/>
```

The last button supposed to change visibility of the StackPanel. However, this code doesn`t work. Why it doesn't work? Any other version that can help me? Would be thankful for any help, article or alternative solution for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have StackPanelVis property in your VM, but change static field in the converter.

First you need to remove it from the converter.

```
public class StakPanelToVisible : IValueConverter
{
     // public static bool StackPanelVis; // remove this one
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     { 
          // value = StackPanelVis; // and this one
          return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
     }
     public object ConvertBack(...) {empty}
}
```

Second, change command implementation to change property in your VM.

```
private void SetAddingProperties()
    {
        TextInducator = "Add";
        StackPanelVis = true;
    }
```

Third, in you StackPanelVis call OnPropertyChanged("StackPanelVis"):

```
private bool _stackPanelVis;
public bool StackPanelVis 
{ 
    get { return _stackPanelVis; } 
    set {
        if (value == _stackPanelVis) return;
        _stackPanelVis = value;
        OnProperyChanged("StackPanelVis");
    }
}
```

Your VM must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Also, you can use builtin [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your converter should look like this:

```
class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Boolean && (bool)value)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and should be referenced either in your App.xaml or in the file that you want to use it (below is the implementation for App.xaml)

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StakPanelToVisible" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Also your StackPanelVis property should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in order to let the View know that it was changed from the code (it should look more like this):

```
private bool isStackPanelVisible;
public bool IsStackPanelViesible
{
    get { return isStackPanelVisible; }
    set 
    {
        isStackPanelVisible = value;
        //RaisePropertyChanged from your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```